Which direction does Sphincs+ work in?
I was reading the Sphincs+ paper, and several other sites about the signing process. I became confused when given pictures compared to the text. I am not too sure on the direction Sphincs+ operates in. If starting from the top, is a public key and secret key generated, which is then given to the lower trees? If this is the case how do we determine which path the FORS algorithm takes. My initial assumption was given a message, we sign with FORS, and work our way up. However, this makes me confused on where the public key at the top root comes in. I have attached a picture of a hypertree from the official Sphincs+ paper.
I am fairly new to cryptography and any clarification on this would be great!


Answering based on my experience implementing SLH-DSA (standardization name of SPHINCS+)
Signing
The message is hashed using one of the hashing subroutines (1 of 6) to choose a authentication path - starting from the lowest FORS signature, all the way through the XMSS^MT hypertree.
Each layer signs the public key of a lower layer, so in reality, it operates from bottom up.
Key-Pair Generation
Since all lower entities can be derived from the key components and the synthesized ADRS address structure, only the top-level XMSS key-pair is computed during keygen.

In that case what does the top level key pair do then? Is it to verify the signature?

@fuego_muego The top-most keypair (PK.root) verifies the top-most XMSS signature, which verifies the next XMSS sig, which in turn the next, until the FORS sig at the bottom. (Actually it's not sig that's verified, it's the PK generated from the signature verification routine that's verified, but that's a minor detail you don't need to concern until you're more familiar with SPHINCS+).
